# PHP trait and 502 error

Tags: php, apache, nginx, traits

We have two virtual servers, it's development and production server. At developments server all works fine, but when project was deployed to production, we have an error: **502 Bad Gateway** at some project pages, where we are using [php traits](https://www.php.net/traits):

```
  class Product extends PublicComponent
  {
       use FileUploader; // When this line was removed, all works

       ...
  }
```

At both servers we using the same configuration, is **nginx+apache+php5.4.14**.
PHP error log is empty, and apache error log says: connection refused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the production machine run APC?

Comment: We tried to install it, but is nothing has changed with APC or without it.

Comment: I see, there was an issue with traits and APC once. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59888

Comment: Yes, but as i said, without APC does not work